# How To Select All Columns From Inherited Class with LINQ and C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I've got an entity I created using Entity Framework's auto code gen and don't want to modify that entry, as I regenerate that code on every table alter.  For the sake of a single EF query, I've created an inherited entity that adds one extra column, SessionId as showing below.

```
public class SpeakerWithSessionIdAdded : Speaker
{
    public int SessionId { get; set; }
}
```

Where Speaker is defined as below but with about 100 total column (I do know there should be less columns, but it is was it is right now).,

```
public class Speaker {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string firstName {get;set;}
  public string lastName {get;set;}
  ... MANY MORE COLUMNS
}
```

I have a LINQ query as follows where I want to get out all the columns plus the one I added (SessionId).  Is there any easy way to do this without using either reflection, or by hand listing every column I want to show?

```
var speakersWithSessionIdAdded = await
    (from sessionPresenter in _dbContext.SessionPresenter
    join speaker in _dbContext.Speakerson sessionPresenter.SpeakerId equals attendee.Id
    where sessionIds.Contains(sessionPresenter.SessionId)
    select new SpeakerWithSessionIdAdded
    {
        SessionId = sessionPresenter.SessionId,
        Id = attendee.Id,
        UserFirstName = attendee.UserFirstName,
        UserLastName = attendee.UserLastName,
        Email = attendee.Email,
        Username = attendee.Username,
        UserBio = attendee.UserBio,
        AllowHtml = attendee.AllowHtml
        .. I DON'T WANT TO LIST OUT 100 MORE LINES HERE FOR EVERY PROPERTY
    }).ToListAsync();

return speakersWithSessionIdAdded.ToLookup(r => r.SessionId);
```

}

Comment: Writing lines manually is one-time job, you would done it in less time than writing this question ;)

Comment: Use AutoMapper and map `Speaker` to `SpeakerWithSessionIdAdded`. The best solution as long as LINQ doesn't have a "*" operator.